# DrawerLayout is not showing on my preview window.How to fix this?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have added a drawerlayout to my app. But it is not being displayed. And when I run the app on emulator it opens and then closes by itself.
[here is the screenshot of the preview window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLY7p.jpg)

and here is the layout file:-

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>


</androidx.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here is the buil.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bitsandpizzas"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the **navigation** without navigation drawer not worked

or you can take example from here  its worked for me https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial

Comment: where do i have to add the navigation?

Comment: i send you the link you can check on it . its working for me

Comment: is there any way you can send me screen shots of your code?